# name of matrix of inner products $\langle f_i, f_j\rangle$

Tags: matrices, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Given a Hilbert space $H$ and a number of elements $\phi_i\in H$, does the matrix $M$ with
$$
M_{i,j} := \langle\phi_i, \phi_j\rangle
$$
have any particular name?

Comment: in finite dimension it is called the Gram matrix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That matrix is called the [Gram-matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram_matrix) of the vectors $\{ \phi_i \}$.